# Form not submitting all fields

Tags: php, html

When I click submit on the following form only the Username, Password, and Age values are sent to registration.php:

```
<div style="top:250;left:620;position:absolute;"> <H3> Registration : </H3> </div> 
<form action="Registration.php" method="Post">
<div style="top:300;left:550;position:fixed;"> <H3> Username </H3> </div><input type="Text" name="UserName" style="position:fixed; top:320; left: 675; width:150px; height:25px"><br>
<div style="top:350;left:550;position:fixed;"> <H3> Password </H3> </div><input type="Password" name="Password" style="position:fixed; top:370; left:675; width:150px; height:25px"><br>
<div style="top:400;left:550;position:fixed;"> <H3> Email Address </H3> </div> <input type="Email" name="Email" style="position:fixed; top:420;left:675;width:150px;height:25px;"><br>
<div style="top:450;left:550;position:fixed;"> <H3> First Name </H3> </div> <input type="Text" name="Fname" style="position:fixed;top:470;left:675;witdh:150px;height:25px;"><br>
<div style="top:500;left:550;position:fixed;"> <H3> Last Name </H3> </div> <input type="Text" name="Lname" style="position:fixed;top:520;left:675;witdh:150px;height:25px;"><br>
<div style="top:550;left:550;position:fixed;"> <H3> Age </H3> </div> <input type="Number" name="Age" style="position:fixed;top:570;left:675;witdh:150px;height:25px;"><br>
<input type="submit" name="fSubmit" value="Registration" style="top:600;left:550;position:fixed;width:100px;height:50px"/>
</form>
```

Can anybody tell why the rest of the fields aren't being submitted?

Comment: `type="Text";name="Email"`.  Lose the `;`.

Comment: Inline styling is bad.

Comment: Please do try to make a better title.

Comment: WOW, I thought inline styling was extinct.

Comment: Please perform [basic, automated QA of your markup](http://validator.w3.org/). (Your CSS is also invalid).

Comment: Also, it's `type="text"`.  `text` should be lowercase.

Comment: How are you determining which fields are being submitted?

Comment: Show us your PHP code

Comment: i know that inline styling is bad but i don't want to start CSS for reasons.

Comment: @user2132375 check my answer, I think your problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing uppercase and small letters interchangeably, which you shouldn't.

```
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$lname = $_POST['Lname'];

echo $Email."<br>";
echo $Lname."<br>";
```

The problem is:  `$Lname` is not same as `$lname` and `$email` is not same as `$Email` due to  [**case sensitivity**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) of variables in PHP.

So, you need to respect the rule, i.e. declare & reference variables of the same case.

Comment: OMG THX :D i don't know how it happend to me :D im C# Objective C and C++ Programer there's case sensitive everywhere. thx so much bro

Answer (score 3):

You have a `;` after `input type="text"` . You didn't have `=` before `fSubmit`.

UPDATE:  `witdh=150px` must be `width:150px` in the style. Otherwise, it breaks the three input fields `email`, `lastname` and `firstname`.

Nothing to do but: `top` and `left` must take a `px` string after each number.

Comment: Changed it, Still same error. =  is Copy-Paste's Fault, i have it in code, but doesn't work. it only send Username,Password And Age

Comment: Does your `Registration.php` file actually start with a capital letter? If not, lowercase the "R" in the form action. Also, lowercase the "P" in `method="Post"` - not required but better.

Comment: @AdamD He said, only three values are being submitted, so what case the file is named is irrelevant because, some it is already being submitted

Comment: @phpNoOb - no more irrelevant than asking for his 'PHP'. He didn't say it wasn't being processed, he stated that it was not posting the values.

Comment: It's the style attribute which break the input fields. (@see my update)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is an error in your HTML at **line 5**:

```
 <div style="top:400;left:550;position:fixed;"><h3> Email Address </h3></div><input type="Text";name="Email" style="position:fixed; top:420; left:675; width:150px; height:25px;"><br>
```

You need to remove semicolon `;` character between `type="Text"` and `name="Email"`.

I think that this could break your HTML.